# Error if ifstream is empty on first test of while

Tags: c++, file-io, segmentation-fault

I have an open input file, `f`, that contains integers, and I have an integer variable `i`.

I do:

```
cout << "going in, ";
while(f >> i){
    cout << "made it in, ";
    //do stuff
}
cout << "and out." << endl;
```

If `f` is empty, instead of just failing the condition and continuing, the output is:

`going in, Segmentation fault: 11`

Why does this attempt to test fail so ungracefully, and only if it fails on the first time? It works as intended and expected if `f` has one or more ints.

Comment: Are you supposed to test for EOF before using the stream extraction operator?

Comment: If `EOF` there's nothing in `f` to assign to `i`, so it should just fail? I'll try.

Comment: The segmentation fault may happen in the `//do stuff` part since `cout` is not flushed yet. You could use unbuffered `cerr` to perform more experiment.

Comment: You do not have to test for EOF (in fact, you should not) prior to attempting to extract.  The extraction will fail (causing your while to break out instantly) when the input fails (bad data, EOF, or file is not open).  There is something else going on in the code you are not showing that is causing your segmentation fault.  To get a better answer, you'll need to show more of your real code (or debug it yourself).

Comment: Doing `if (f.eof()) return;` beforehand had no visible effect.

Comment: Use a debugger to know where the segfault occured. Due to buffering, `cout` are not reliable in this case.

Comment: The code is fine - your example is incomplete

Comment: The only thing inside `while` (apart from the `cout` I *thought* helped debug) is `my_func(i)`. Sorry for incomplete example - I try to keep generic so others can benefit, it bugs me to be on the other side.

Comment: I would suspect that something is getting initialized in the `while`, and being used after it.  And of course, if you never enter the while, it never gets initialized.

Comment: @jia103 __NO__.  You never test for EOF until after input has failed.

Comment: Anything initialised in `while` is initialised in that other function, so it's out of scope there even if it were used afterward surely?

Comment: @hivert His second output uses `std::endl`, so he does the flush.  And most implementations will make `std::cout` unit buffered if it is connected to an interactive device.

Comment: @OllieFord Who knows?  The other function could set a global pointer, for example.

Comment: I have no global variables.

Comment: Note: There is no need to test for EOF (That test is often useless or wrong, unless you want to ensure all data is consumed or you are using unformatted input)

Comment: Not reproducible. [Live demo](http://ideone.com/i7ixyq). Show a complete compilable problem that fails on you, otherwise it cannot really be discussed.

Comment: Can you give us the complete code please? :)

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is:

```
while( f>>i, !f.bad() )
```

Comment: while( f>>i, !f.bad()&&!f.fail() )